# Sencha pie Chart in Android Webview

Tags: android, sencha-touch

I am using webview in android for loading html page,sencha pie chart is not displaying in webview,it is showing error like

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'height' of undefined`

and

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setStyle' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/lib/touch-charts.js:1
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem.

Comment: trying to set style for component which is not in viewport, is that project worked in web browser?

Comment: Thanks for your reply,the project is not working in web browser(Android Tablet),but it is working fine in web browser(iPhone).

Comment: why don't you first run that project in chrome and check for the console errors ?. you may get detailed error

Comment: In chrome console i am not getting any error,project is working fine,only in android device it is not working,i am using sencha charts,which is not displayed in android device.

Comment: Android version 4.2.2 and I am using sencha-touch.js 1.0,touch-chart.js 1.0.

Comment: actually if you use touch2.1 above you don't need separate touch-chart.js

Comment: ok,so problem is with sencha-touch version?

Comment: I think so, because you said your project having no error.. works on system web browser but not on tablet browser.

Comment: But with same sencha touch version,chart is displaying fine in ipad.

Comment: if you problem not solved then post you code and let me test

Comment: for upgrading sencha 1.0 to sencha 2.1 I added sencha all.js,sencha debug.js,sencha touch.js from downloaded sencha 2.1 zip,i am getting lot of errors,is there any steps to be followed for upgrading to sencha touch 2.1?

Comment: you just need to add sencha-touch-all.js only.. why you are adding many sencha js file

Comment: @viswa:I have added sencha-touch.all.js and removed other .js files,still i am getting errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you use sencha touch 2.1 and above version, you don't need to include separate `touch-chart.js`

Even i tried pie chart using `Sencha touch 2.2.0` and tested on `Android 4.1` version tablet browser. It's working, but animating slowly.

Just try to upgrade the sencha touch version to 2.2 (latest at this moment).

Comment: Thanks for replying,will upgrade the version and check.

Comment: for upgrading sencha 1.0 to sencha 2.1 I added sencha all.js,sencha debug.js,sencha touch.js from downloaded sencha 2.1 zip,i am getting lot of errors,is there any steps to be followed for upgrading to sencha touch 2.1?

Comment: I am getting errors like,08-23 07:10:55.613: E/Web Console(770): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: Safari at file:///android_asset/www/lib/sencha-touch-all.js:15

Comment: @jaya sudha you just need to add sencha-touch-all.js only.. why you are adding many sencha js file

Comment: :I am getting errors like this "Uncaught ReferenceError: App is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/app/views/login/IndexView.js:1",help me in solving this?

Comment: @jayasudha post your IndexView.js file

Comment: App.views.LoginIndex = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
  margin: '0 0 0 0',
  html: "<a href='#Login/home' class='button' id='loginbutton' ></a><input value='innovationlab@hcl.com'"+
    " type='text' id='txtUserName'/>"+
    "<input type='password' value='hcl@1234' id='txtPassWord'/>"+
    "<a onclick='setRhoconnectIP();' class='button' id='ipsettings'></a>",

    cls:"loginIndex",
  styleHtmlContent: true,
  style: "background-image:url('res/images/login.png');",
  

});
Ext.reg('LoginIndex', App.views.LoginIndex);

function locate(){
 
 window.location.href = "#Login/home";
 
}

Comment: :I am also getting many errors,is there anything need to be changed in the design code?

Comment: @jayasudha i suggest you to follow MVC in sencha touch. until i see your full code i can't tell what problem in your code.

Comment: :One clarification,for upgrading sencha 1.0 to sencha 2.1.1 it is enough to add only sencha-touch-all.js right?

Comment: @jayasudha ya, sencha-touch-all.js and sencha-touch.css is enough

Comment: :I am getting errors like "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'draw' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/app/routes/routes.js:1
","Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function at file:///android_asset/www/app/views/login/HomeView.js:13
",for previous errors i have changed according to MVC in sencha Touch,but for this errors i couldn,t able to find the reason for the error.